# Bash input to two separate prompts

Tags: bash

```
( echo 'USER blah\n' ; echo 'PASS blah\n') | nc ...
```

"nc... "
has two input prompts. The answer to the first one must be in the form 'USER blah...', and the answer to the second one must be in the form "PASS blah...". In my bash script above, the two inputs are sometimes treated as input to the first prompt only, NOT one for the username and one for the password. How can I make sure that the two inputs (two echos) are indeed treated / used as inputs to the two separate prompts?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-e` flag to the first `echo`? Otherwise `echo` just prints `\n` literally.

Comment: [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) might of some help here

Comment: Try sending CRLF-terminated strings with `nc`: `(echo 'USER blah'; echo 'PASS blah') | nc -c ...`.

Comment: What do the `nc` prompts look like? You probably have to wait until the for the second prompt before sending the second response.

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
(echo -e "USER blah" "\n""PASS blah") | nc ...
```

This line will pass the two inputs separated by the newline which is usually sufficient to convince the program after the pipe that the two inputs are in fact two inputs.

Comment: You should quote `\n`: either `\\n`, `'\n'` or `$'\n'` without the `-e` switch. Otherwise `echo` sees only a plain `n`, since the shell swallows the backslash.

Comment: @Boldewyn, thanks, rookie mistake. You're right, it was wrong.

Comment: The `-e` option with `echo` makes the script less portable. Check [\[ this \]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Builtins).

Comment: You don't need the space. A proper newline is what causes `nc`'s read to stop reading at the first prompt.

Comment: In fact, the space causes a *literal* space to be output after the `blah`, which is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: @chepner Do you know, then, what I can do instead to fix this?

Comment: `(echo -e "USER blah\nPASS blah") | nc ...`

Answer (score -1):

Use some delay:

```
( echo 'USER blah\n' ; sleep 1; echo 'PASS blah\n') | nc ...
```